# C - DNS proxy serve every request any time

Tags: c, dns, udp, nonblocking

I created DNS proxy in C like this:

```
"socket" - create socket to serve client
"bind" - bind that socket
while (true) {
    "recvfrom" - a package from socket 
    "socket" - create socket for dns server
    (1)
    "sendto" - send package to dns server
    "recvfrom" - respond from dns server
    "sendto" - send respond to client
}
```

It's working. But what if I get another request when I am at position (1)? How can I add some queue with waiting requests? How to change this that I serve every request even if I am working on another?

Comment: Shouldn't a DNS proxy open a *server* socket in the first place, to allow incoming requests, and then forward them to the upstream server with a *client* socket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `listen()` on the server socket, and `listen` allows you to specify a backlog of connections. You will be able to handle up to that number of new client arrivals per cycle.

Then you cyclically run `select()` on the server socket and any outstanding client sockets, maintaining a list of them:

```
   select(nfds, readfds, writefds, errorfds, timeout);
```

when `select` exits (unless it's timed out) you will inspect the three return lists and handle any sockets ready for reading, writing, or in error state, and dispatch them appropriately.

You will find a detailed example [here](http://www.binarytides.com/server-and-client-example-with-c-sockets-on-linux/) (it's for Linux, but easily portable).

Answer (score 0):

Using nonblocking sockets would only be beneficial if you write your service to be asynchronous, i.e. not wait for response to your upstream DNS query before waiting on another packet coming from downstream.

You should consider `select`ing both sockets, and when a packet comes in, you figure out where it came from. If it is from downstream, you send a request to the DNS upstream; if it is a response from the DNS, find out which client sent the original request and respond there. In that structure, there is no location in the code at which you are unresponsive to one of your sockets.